# WAR file not getting deployed in Jboss 5.0 server

Tags: jboss, war

I have a developed a web project which uses struts2+springs3+hibernate3 integration. I was successfully able to build it and run it on a Tomcat server. But when I tried to deploy the same WAR in Jboss 5.0 server, it was throwing the following error:

```
2012-08-24 15:38:38,461 ERROR [STDERR] (main) SLF4J: slf4j-api 1.6.x (or later) is incompatible with this binding.
2012-08-24 15:38:38,477 ERROR [STDERR] (main) SLF4J: Your binding is version 1.5.5 or earlier.
2012-08-24 15:38:38,477 ERROR [STDERR] (main) SLF4J: Upgrade your binding to version 1.6.x. or 2.0.x
2012-08-24 15:38:38,555 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/ServiceCatalog-ICC]] (main) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/resources/hibernateSessionFactory.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1403)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4370)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:352)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:140)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:459)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at $Proxy35.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:672)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:444)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:146)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:104)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:45)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:169)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1285)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1003)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1024)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:944)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:627)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:541)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.loadProfile(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:265)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:143)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:409)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:209)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton()Lorg/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder;
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:121)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:268)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:241)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newConfiguration(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:813)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:549)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
    ... 70 more
2012-08-24 15:38:38,571 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (main) Error listenerStart
2012-08-24 15:38:38,571 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (main) Context [/ServiceCatalog-ICC] startup failed due to previous errors
```

As per some expert's suggestion I tried removing slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar jar file from my project's WAR and redeployed it again. But this time it was showing the following problem:

```
2012-08-24 15:45:28,852 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/ServiceCatalog-ICC]] (main) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/resources/hibernateSessionFactory.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1403)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4370)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:352)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:140)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:459)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
    at $Proxy35.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:672)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:444)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:146)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:104)
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:45)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:169)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1285)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1003)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1024)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:944)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:627)
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:541)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.loadProfile(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:265)
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:143)
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:409)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:209)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyHibernateValidatorLegacyConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1681)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyConstraintsToDDL(Configuration.java:1653)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1445)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.hibernate.validator.ClassValidator.<init>(java.lang.Class, java.util.ResourceBundle, org.hibernate.validator.MessageInterpolator, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2721)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2002)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.applyHibernateValidatorLegacyConstraintsOnDDL(Configuration.java:1669)
    ... 77 more
2012-08-24 15:45:28,993 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (main) Error listenerStart
2012-08-24 15:45:28,993 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (main) Context [/ServiceCatalog-ICC] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I am unable to spot out whether the problem is in my set of jars which I had used or in the Jboss server which I am using.

Answer (score 0):

the 3 first line don't suggest to remove the jar but to update the version of it